# Using the UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator animateAlongsideTransition method

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, ios-animations

I have a ViewController lets say `ViewControllerA` and a ViewController lets say `ViewControllerB`.

`ViewControllerB` is modally presented from `ViewControllerA` using a custom transition.

In ViewControllerA:

```
-(void)buttonClicked...
{
  ViewControllerB * controller = [[ViewControllerB alloc] init];
  [controller setModalPresentationStyle:UIModalPresentationCustom];
  controller.transitioningDelegate = self;
  [self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

In ViewControllerA -

```
#pragma mark - UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate

- 

(id<UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning>)animationControllerForPresentedController:(UIViewController *)presented
                                                                      presentingController:(UIViewController *)presenting
                                                                          sourceController:(UIViewController *)source 
{

   FadeInWithPopAnimator* fadeInAnimator = [[FadeInWithPopAnimator alloc] init];
   return fadeInAnimator;
 }
```

I have an custom Animator class called `FadeInWithPopAnimator` which implements the transitionDuration and animationTransition methods.

I want to animate a couple of views on the presented viewcontroller - `ViewControllerB`, 0.2 seconds after the transition animation starts.

I have read the docs online and it looks like using a transitionCoordinator is the way to go. 
But where should I put the code ?

1) While calling the presentViewController in `ViewControllerA` ?

2) In the Animator class ?

3) In viewWillAppear of `ViewControllerA`?

I have tried a couple of things but it is not giving me results and examples are hard to find.

Answer (score 5):

TransitionCoordinator on the presented view controller will be set after a view controller's animation has started, so in `viewWillAppear` of the presented view controller. Add any extra animations using `animateAlongsideTransition:completion:` on the transition coordinator. In your case in ViewControllerB:

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear];

    [self.transitionCoordinator animateAlongsideTransition:^(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinatorContext>  _Nonnull context) {

        // change any properties on your views

    } completion:^(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinatorContext>  _Nonnull context) {


    }];
}
```